# How do i remove the top line in a CSV file (the coloumn headers)?

Tags: php, csv

I have put together a script which will upload a CSV file and then extract the data into an already made table. I want to make it so the first line(the column headers) will not be inserted into the table, but the rest of the data will be.

```
  $fp = fopen($_SESSION['filename'],"r");


while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)

{
    $import="INSERT into csv_table(name,address,age) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";

    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());

}

fclose($fp);
```

this is the part of the code i use to extract the data from the csv file.

Thank You very much for any help with this matter!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just put the following before the `while` loop to read the first line:

```
fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ",");
```

Thereafter the `while` loop starts with the second line instead.

Answer (score 1):

Underthink it.

Create a boolean flag on the outside, and toggle it once you enter the loop instead of importing, using an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a blank read as such:

```
$fp = fopen($_SESSION['filename'],"r");
$headerLine = true;

while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)

{
        if($headerLine) { $headerLine = false; }
        else {
                $import="INSERT into csv_table(name,address,age) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";

                mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
        }

}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use out of loop `fgetcsv()` function and then, after your array, print value second line:

```
 if (($handle = fopen($target_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {    
   $i=1;
   fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    echo "</pre>";  
    $i++;
  }
}
```