# PHP PDO related: Update SQL statement not updating the content of the database 

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo

I am trying to implement an update statement using a prepared statement in a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) script, but it appears that it is not updating the record in the database and I am not sure why and so would appreciate if you can share some insights.

#### Code

```
$query = "UPDATE DatTable SET DF_PARTY_ID = :party_id,
          DF_PARTY_CODE = :party_code,
          DF_CONNECTION_ID = :connection_id WHERE DF_PARTY_ID = ':party_id'";
$stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':party_id', $data[0], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':party_code', $data[1], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':connection_id', $data[2], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

[Inspiring solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381474/how-to-remove-or-avoid-inserting-column-headers-when-importing-a-separated-value/2381490#2381490) leading to this approach. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I don't think it'll help but pdo can be strange at times. Why do you reset your "SET DF_PARTY_ID = :party_id" that you use to select in the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not help, but why are you only binding 3 variables, when there are 4?  I can't say that I have experience doing this in PHP, but in Perl and Oracle it would throw an error.  I'd try binding the 2 SETs and the 1 WHERE, and removing the first assignment, and see if that works.

Comment: I have only 3 variables mentioned, can you point me to 4th one as I do not see it.

Comment: UPDATE DatTable SET DF_PARTY_ID = :party_id (--1--),
          DF_PARTY_CODE = :party_code (--2--),
          DF_CONNECTION_ID = :connection_id (--3--) WHERE DF_PARTY_ID = ':party_id'" (--4--)

Also, since you quote the 4th var, which is really a duplicate of the 1st, I don't see how that could work.

Comment: So here is my confusion, how do I differenciate party_id while binding their values any suggestions.

Comment: It appears to me that you only have one value for PARTY_ID and you are not changing it.  So you do need to filter on it (thus the where clause) but you don't need to change it.  Therefore, my suggestion is to a) don't update it at all, as mentioned above and b) remove the tics around it.

In other words:
$q = "UPDATE DatTable 
      SET DF_PARTY_CODE = :party_code, 
          DF_CONNECTION_ID = :connection_id 
      WHERE DF_PARTY_ID = :party_id";

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `party_id` you are trying to update exists in the database.

Also, if your table is `InnoDB`, make sure that you have `autocommit` on or issue an explicit commit after the update is made.

Comment: Yes it does exists in the database and so am wondering as to why it is not updating the value in there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of guessing, basic error handling must be implemented:

```
$arr = $stmt->errorInfo();
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to do what you're trying to do.

Your UPDATE statement basically says update the key and two values based on the NEW value, since party_id is in the SET and WHERE clauses.

You may want to change your prepared statement to this:

UPDATE DatTable SET DF_PARTY_ID = :party_id,
DF_PARTY_CODE = :party_code,
DF_CONNECTION_ID = :connection_id
WHERE DF_PARTY_ID = ':old_party_id'

bind your NEW party_id value to :party_id and the CURRENT one to :old_party_id